# Backround mode is not working when ionic app is close from recent?

Tags: ionic-framework, background-process, ionic5, foreground, background-mode

How can I run the continuous app in background mode, I am using ionic 5, I have tested in android 9 + devices it's not working well when I remove the app from recent the background mode is also killed not working well. Please give me any suggestions for that issue.

**Thanks In Advance**

Comment: try this `this.platform.resume.subscribe((e) => {  }); this.platform.pause.subscribe((e) => {});`

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using one of the plugins supported by ionic framework for the intended task?

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/foreground-service

Comment: I want solution for when app is close from recent , The app is running in background